# show that if $a,K$ are positive integers and $a≠m^k$ then $a^\frac{1}{K}$ is irrational.

Tags: proof-verification, irrational-numbers

show that if $a,K$ are positive integers and $a≠m^k$ then $a^\frac{1}{K}$ is irrational.

I assumed $a=m^K$ and $a^\frac{1}{K}∈ℝ\backslash ℚ$,it's clear that $a$ is a power of $m$, means $a=m×...×m$($K$ copies of $m$), then if $K$ is even and $m$ is a negative integer we have $a^\frac{1}{K}=\left|m\right|$ otherwise $a^\frac{1}{K}=m$ , in both cases $a^\frac{1}{K}$ is equail to an element which is not irrational, a contradiction,implies $a≠m^k⇒a^\frac{1}{K}∈ℝ\backslash ℚ$ as desired.

I DON'T KNOW MY PROOF IS CORRECT OR NOT...

Comment: I think I should make a contradiction by assuming that if $a≠m^{k}$ then $a^{\frac{1}{K}}$ is rational.but I don't know how

Comment: This proof is not valid at all. You have proven that $\sqrt[K]{m^K}$ is rational. How does this prove that $\sqrt[K]{a}$ is irrational otherwise?

Comment: ok, it's not right, so you tell me the right form

Comment: You are trying to prove that $A \Rightarrow B$, by showing $\neg A$ and $B$ giving a contradiction. This is not the same thing. Assuming $A$ and $\neg B$ and deriving a contradiction gives a proof. i.e. assume $a \neq m^k$ and $a^{1/K}$ rational and derive a contradiction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Assume $a \neq m^k$ and that there exist $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ coprime s.t. $a^{\frac{1}{k}} = \frac{p}{q}$. Try then to derive a contradiction.

---

Let $a,k \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. for any $m \in \mathbb{Z}: a \neq m^k$  and assume there exist $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ coprime s.t. $a^{\frac{1}{k}} = \frac{p}{q}$. Then $a = \frac{p^k}{q^k}$, hence $a q^{k-1} = \frac{p^k}{q}$. The left hand side is an integer, so $\frac{p^k}{q} \in \mathbb{Z}$. But $p,q$ are coprime, so $q = 1$, and thus $a = p^k$. A contradiction to the assumption since $p \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus $a^{\frac{1}{k}}$ is irrational.

Comment: $∃a,k∈ℕ^{+}:a^{\frac{1}{k}}∈ℚ→a^{\frac{1}{k}}∈ℤ ∨a^{\frac{1}{k}}∈ℝ\backslashℚ$.
given $a≠m^{k},m∈ℤ$, I argue with the contradiction: $a≠m^{k}$ but $a^{\frac{1}{k}}∈ℚ$ ,therefore
 $∃p,q∈ℤ(q≠0):a^{\frac{1}{k}}=\frac{p}{q}$,and the fraction is in the lowest term, means gcd$(p,q)=1$,we have $a=\frac{p^k}{q^k}$, since $p∤q$ hence $p^{k}∤ q^{k}$, implies $a∈ℚ\backslashℤ$, which is a contradiction,since $a$ was supposed to be an integer,concludes the statement is true."now is my proof right?"

Comment: Firstly, the statement in the beginning is not correct. I guess what you want to write is: $$\forall a, k \in \mathbb{N}: a^{\frac{1}{k}} \in \mathbb{Z} \vee a^{\frac{1}{k}} \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$$. Also, having $a = \frac{p^k}{q^k}$ with $p \nmid q$ does not imply $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Take for example $a = \frac{5^2}{3^2}$.

Comment: I really don't know what should I do, if you know the correct form then write!

Comment: I have edited the answer to include an full answer to your question. If this answers your question, please mark it as an answer such that it won't show up in the "unanswered" queue.

Comment: you've made a contradiction, but assume $p^{k}∈ℤ$, in the sense that $p^{k}∈ℕ$,  now the contradiction does not work, because the both side $a$ and $p^{k}$ are elements in the set ℕ.

Comment: I don’t understand your comment

Comment: can you please explain clearly why we have a contradiction in your answer?I don't get it and I don't know how it implies that $a^{\frac{1}{k}}$ is irrational.

Comment: In general, what I’m doing in order to prove $A \Rightarrow B$ is to assume $A$ and $\neg B$ and deduce a contradiction - in this case I’m showing $\neg A$. This then proves that $B$ needs to be true, given that $A$ is true i.e. that $A \Rightarrow B$. In your case, statement $A$ is $a \neq m^k$ and the statement $B$ is that $a^{1/k}$ is irrational.

Comment: In the 3rd to last sentence, I’m showing that there does exist an integer, such that $a=m^k$, which contradicts the assumption